# Fastest way to parse large character strings element by element

Tags: r

I have extremely large binary files (~200 million characters) that I am trying to turn into human readable text. The format is unique in that each byte encodes into hex and there are various hex "keys" in the text that describe the format of the following hex values, something like this...

- if the current hex value is "6", the following 4 hex values are taken together and turned into a long int.
- if the current hex value is "4", the following hex value is taken as an int.
- if the current hex value doesn't match the other categories, turn it into a character.

I dont believe this can be vectorized in any way, as the input string has to be stepped through element by element. My current implementation takes roughly 300 seconds to work through 1 million characters. The code is below. My similarly structured code in Python takes roughly 8 seconds but cant be used in my case for business reasons.

How can this be sped up? The loop using my parseLine function can be configured to write to a text file once with the collective translation or write once on every pass. Both run in similar times.

EDIT: I have added an example of a line read from the target file and its translation.

```
#fraw is input file read as binary by read_file_raw function  
parseline <- function(fraw,index){
  i=index
  s=""
  continue = TRUE

  while (continue == TRUE) {
    tmp <- fraw[i]

    #Testing. Currently the best guess for most inclusive end of line sequence of characters.
    eot = paste0(fraw[i],fraw[i+1],fraw[i+2],fraw[i+3],fraw[i+4],fraw[i+5],fraw[i+6],fraw[i+7],fraw[i+8],fraw[i+9],fraw[i+10])

    if (eot == "17faae4e0b09656e76000a"){
      continue = FALSE
      break
    } else if (tmp==0){   #empty space
      s=paste0(s,"|")
      i=i+1
    } else if (tmp==2){   #binary 0
      s=paste(s,"0")
      i=i+1
    } else if (tmp==3){   #binary 1
      s=paste(s,"1")
      i=i+1
    } else if (tmp==4){   #short int from 1 hex pairs
      v=as.numeric(paste0("0x",fraw[i+1]))
      s=paste(s,v)
      i=i+2
    } else if (tmp==5){   #int from 2 hex pairs
      v=as.numeric(paste0("0x",fraw[i+1],fraw[i+2]))
      s=paste(s,v)
      i=i+3
    } else if (tmp==6){   #long int from 4 hex pairs
      v=as.numeric(paste0("0x",fraw[i+1],fraw[i+2],fraw[i+3],fraw[i+4]))
      s=paste(s,v)
      i=i+5
    } else if (tmp==7){   #float
      v=paste0(fraw[i+1],fraw[i+2],fraw[i+3],fraw[i+4])
      t=readBin(as.raw(strtoi(substring(v, (step<-seq(1, nchar(v), by=2)), step+1), 16)), "double",n=1,size=4,endian="big")
      s=paste(s,t)
      i=i+5
    } else if (tmp==8){ #double float
      v=paste0(fraw[i+1],fraw[i+2],fraw[i+3],fraw[i+4],fraw[i+5],fraw[i+6],fraw[i+7],fraw[i+8])
      t=readBin(as.raw(strtoi(substring(v, (step<-seq(1, nchar(v), by=2)), step+1), 16)), "double",n=1,size=8,endian="big")
      s=paste(s,t)
      i=i+9
    } else if (tmp %in% c("09","10","11","12","13","0b","0a")){   #tab and stuff
      s=paste0(s,"|")
      i=i+1
    } else if (i > index + 3000000){   #overflow
      continue = FALSE
      break
    } else {   #everything else
      s=paste0(s,rawToChar(tmp))
      i=i+1
    }
  }
  return(list(s,i))
}

#Loop to utilize parseLine function on full file
ptm <- proc.time()
max=1000000
k=1
i=1
#final<-c()
while (k < max){  
  results <- parseline(fraw,k)
  #final[i]=results[1]
  k = as.numeric(results[2])+11  
  if (i == 1){
    write(as.character(results[1]),"test.txt", append=FALSE)
  }
  else {
    write(as.character(results[1]),"test.txt", append=TRUE)
  }  
  i=i+1  
}
#write_lines(final,"test.txt", append=FALSE)
proc.time() - ptm

#To run parseline on example text
fraw = example text #replace with name of variable
results = parseline(fraw,1)
results[1] #to get readout
```

Example hex string

```
06 5d 47 09 01 02 05 02 e4 00 09 74 61 67 00 09 53 46 2d 43 42 44 30 00 09 66 6d 74 00 04 53 09 74 79 70 00 09 53 46 58 41 78 4d 43 3a 41 52 41 5f 66 69 6c 74 65 72 5f 70
61 72 61 6d 5f 73 74 72 75 63 74 00 09 64 61 74 00 0b 09 65 6e 61 62 6c 65 64 00 09 54 52 55 45 00 09 66 65 65 64 5f 66 6f 72 77 61 72 64 5f 66 61 63 74 6f 72 73 00 0a 08
00 02 db 80 00 1d 32 48 08 07 70 db 70 00 0f 9c 10 08 00 00 00 00 07 70 db a8 08 07 70 db 90 00 76 5b 70 00 09 66 65 65 64 62 61 63 6b 5f 66 61 63 74 6f 72 73 00 0a 08 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 04 08 07 70 dc 50 0c d6 af b8 08 07 70 db e0 00 00 00 00 08 07 70 db a0 01 0e ce a4 00 09 73 74 61 72 74 5f 76 61 6c 75 65 73 00 0a 08 00 00 00 00 07 70
dc f4 08 07 70 db c0 01 10 4c e4 08 0c d6 b0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c7 fe 16 ef 17
```

Translated text

```
1564936449 0 740||tag||SF-CBD0||fmt| 83|typ||SFXAxMC:ARA_filter_param_struct||dat|||enabled||TRUE||feed_forward_factors|| 3.97373420744674e-309 7.79020350607574e-273 6.1677562359179e-316 7.79042916642816e-273||feedback_factors|| 1.97626258336499e-323 7.79178340311585e-273 7.79099327693562e-273 7.79054200747996e-273||start_values|| 6.16777263889734e-316 7.7907676569376e-273 8.11204229957035e-247|||
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: Where does the `read_file_raw` function come from?

Comment: can you do this with `Rcpp` ?

Comment: read_file_raw comes from readr

Comment: Edited post with examples